# Is Rigveda 10:138:4 is asking to kill Non Hindus?

Tags: vedas, rig-veda, atheism

> अनाधृष्टानि धृषितो व्यास्यन्निधीँर**देवाँ** अमृणदयास्यः । मासेव सूर्यो वसु पुर्यमा ददे गृणानः शत्रूँरशृणाद्विरुक्मता॥४॥

> 4. He boldly cast down forts which none had e'er assailed: unwearied he destroycd the **godless** treasure-stores. Like Sun and Moon he took the stronghold's wealth away, and, praised in song, demolished foes with flashing dart.

Adeva word is translated as godless here. Is this verse praying for destruction of Non Hindus or it's meaning is something else.

Comment: Which translation is it

Comment: @DarkKnight Griffith's translation

Comment: @DarkKnight damodar satwelkar and sri ram Sharma translation is also same as Griffith one.

Comment: it's not asking US to kill non-hindus. the godless will meet with their demise in their own deserved way. here godless doesn't just mean the label hindu/non-hindu, muslim/non-muslim etc. but whether or not you live life according to the principles of those religions.

Comment: Here's R L Kashyap's translation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYB4Z.png

Comment: @sv where did you get R L Kashyap's translation. If possible can you give the ki k of the pdf

Comment: It used to be on archive.org later they took it down. Posting download links to copyright material is not recommended on SE. @DarkKnight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you look at the Hindi translation of it here on [Vedakosh](http://www.vedakosh.com/rig-veda/mandal-10/sukta-138/mantra-rig-10-138-004), the complete translation says:

> (धृषितः) शत्रुओं का धर्षणकर्ता दबानेवाला (अनाधृष्टानि) न धर्षण करने
> योग्य बलों को (वि-आस्यत्) विशेषरूप से फेंकता है (अयास्यः) अभ्रान्त-न
> थका हुआ **(निधीन्-अदेवान्) बलनिधि नास्तिक उद्दण्ड शत्रुओं को** (अमृणात्)
> हिंसित करता है (मासा इव सूर्यः) अपनी रश्मि से सूर्य रस खींच लेता है,
> उसी प्रकार (पुर्यं वसु-आददे) शत्रु के पुरि नगरी में होनेवाले धन को बल
> को ले लेता है (गृणानः) प्रार्थना में लाया हुआ (विरुक्मता
> शत्रून्-अशृणात्) विशेष तेजस्वी वज्र से शत्रुओं को मारता है ॥४॥

And if I translate the bold part in english i.e           `निधीन्-अदेवान्) बलनिधि नास्तिक उद्दण्ड शत्रुओं को` it means powerful atheist defiant/rude enemy and not godless. It's just another case of misinterpretation by Griffith.

Comment: Aren't 'atheist' and 'godless' same thing? Where exactly is the "misinterpretation"?

Comment: राजा धर्षणशील हो, अहिंसित शस्त्रों से न थकता हुआ शत्रुओं को मारे-बल धनकोषों को वश में करे, सूर्य जैसे रश्मि से रस ले लेता है, सब कुछ शत्रु को स्ववश में ले लेवे, तेजस्वी शस्त्र से शत्रु को मारे ॥४॥ this the English translation

Comment: @SayNoToCensorship - it is the difference between atheist (or agnostic) and anti-theist

Answer (score 3):

Brererton & Jamison RV 10-138

> 3. The Sun unhitched his chariot in the middle of heaven. The Ārya found a match for the
>    Dāsa.The ﬁrm fortiﬁcations of the crafty lord Pipru did Indra throw open, having acted together with Rjiśvan.

> 4. Deﬁant, he threw open the undeﬁable (fortiﬁcations); the unbridled one pulverized the ungodly treasure-houses.Like the Sun with the Moon, he took for his own the goods found in the fortress. Being sung, he shattered his rivals with his ﬂashing (weapon)

It is just another example of the Arya-Non-Arya conflict in the Rig Veda.  These verses are only describing Indra defeating his enemies (Dasas in this case?) - no mass-killing is indicated here.

Answer (score 1):

Rigveda 10:138:4

> **अनाधृष्टानि धृषितो व्यास्यन्निधीँरदेवाँ अमृणदयास्यः । मासेव सूर्यो वसु पुर्यमा ददे गृणानः शत्रूँरशृणाद्विरुक्मता** ॥
>
> > *धृषितः) शत्रुओं का धर्षणकर्ता दबानेवाला (अनाधृष्टानि) न धर्षण करने योग्य बलों को (वि-आस्यत्) विशेषरूप से फेंकता है (अयास्यः) अभ्रान्त-न थका हुआ (निधीन्-अदेवान्) बलनिधि नास्तिक उद्दण्ड शत्रुओं को (अमृणात्) हिंसित करता है (मासा इव सूर्यः) अपनी रश्मि से सूर्य रस खींच लेता है, उसी प्रकार (पुर्यं वसु-आददे) शत्रु के पुरि नगरी में होनेवाले धन को बल को ले लेता है (गृणानः) प्रार्थना में लाया हुआ (विरुक्मता शत्रून्-अशृणात्) विशेष तेजस्वी वज्र से शत्रुओं को मारता है ॥४॥*
> >
> > > Thrifty:) The suppressor of enemies (suppressor) throws (non-distraught) forces that are not repulsive (va-asya) (aasya:) frantic - not tired (nidhin-adevaan) balanidhi atheist defending enemies (amritarat). Eve Surya:) With his Rashmi, Surya draws the juice, in the same way (Puri Vasu-Adde) takes away the wealth that is in the enemy's city (Griानanāh), brought in prayer (Virukmata Shatru -a-ृृrत्a )at) with special glittering thunderbolt. Kills enemies ॥४॥
>
> > *राजा धर्षणशील हो, अहिंसित शस्त्रों से न थकता हुआ शत्रुओं को मारे-बल धनकोषों को वश में करे, सूर्य जैसे रश्मि से रस ले लेता है, सब कुछ शत्रु को स्ववश में ले लेवे, तेजस्वी शस्त्र से शत्रु को मारे ॥४॥*
> >
> > > The king should be crippling, kill enemies with undeserved weapons, and subdue the treasuries, take the juice from the sun like Rashmi, take everything into self-control, kill the enemy with stunning weapons.[Vedakosh](http://www.vedakosh.com/rig-veda/mandal-10/sukta-138/mantra-rig-10-138-004)

So it doesn't say to kill godless or atheist, but enemie.

---

<sup>**NOTE** : I used Google translater to translate the Hindi translation into English</sup>

Comment: How is this different from my answer?

Comment: @Just_Do_It Bro my answer contains original sanskrit verse, english translation

Comment: As long as you got ur ans, all good!